# Slack or Mattermost Alternative, but selfhosted and PHP

Tags: steam

I'm looking for a Slack or Mattermost alternative, but it should be able to using from web, which is currently only possible from PHP I think.

It should have following features:
-Selfhosted
-Team Managment
-Data Storage Support, we want to use only the storage of the domain

I already found an selfhosted CMS, which can do it nearly, but lacks support for Data Storage. It's called rukovoditel.

I wanted to also use Mattermost, but I think, you need a real Server to use it.

What I want?

I need web interface, where 3 of our members can make task and we can talk about the tasks. If any file is needed, one member should be able to upload to the storage, not external, but internal storage of the domain. We can use it as pool for our files. Every member is able to change the data, even delete it. It should be selfhosted and free.